# Add error bars manually to seaborn line marker plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, errorbar

I have columns of `x`, `mean` and `std`. I want to plot line with markers of using seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0,1,2]
mean = [2,1,3]
std = [0.1,0.4,0.2]

sns.lineplot(x=x,y=mean,marker='o')
```

How to add `std` as errorbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that works for me:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x,'y':mean,'std':std})

g = sns.FacetGrid(df, size=5)
g.map(plt.errorbar, "x", "y", "std", marker="o")
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

From seaborn doc,

```
markers : boolean, list, or dictionary, optional
    Object determining how to draw the markers for different levels of the
    ``style`` variable. Setting to ``True`` will use default markers, or
    you can pass a list of markers or a dictionary mapping levels of the
    ``style`` variable to markers. Setting to ``False`` will draw
    marker-less lines.  Markers are specified as in matplotlib.
```

`markers` works with the `style` option of `lineplot`. In your case, use `marker`, which is passed to `plt.plot`, not `markers`:

```
sns.lineplot(x=x,y=mean,marker='o')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: My bad! Will edit this - what about the std error?